# High CPU usage and load with many queues and sessions in ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: spring-boot, docker, activemq-artemis

I have an Artemis broker (2.10.1) running within a Docker container with one address but many (500+) queues. Each queue has a filter attribute, they don't overlap and routing type is multicast.

```
broker
- address: example
  - multicast
    - queue: dummy1 (filter: dummy=1)
    - queue: dummy2 (filter: dummy=2)
    - queue: dummy3 (filter: dummy=3)
    - ...
```

When the client connects the cpu usage for client and broker goes from ~5% up to ~40%, according to htop (~20% normal + ~20% kernel). JMX reports ~10% CPU usage. When changing htop to tree view I can see the ~10% thread and many many 0.x% threads. Queues are empty, I'm neithing producing nor consuming a message. The whole system is (should be) in idle. The client establishes a single connection but one session per queue, resulting in 500+ sessions.

Whats wrong with my configuration? I can't see a reason for having such a CPU usage and load.

**Update:**

I did some more tests and it turns out that the CPU usage/load only happens if Docker is involved.

- broker running in Docker container on host A, pure artemis-core client running (without Docker) on host B: <5% CPU usage
- broker running in Docker container on host A, pure artemis-jms client running (without Docker) on host A: <5% CPU usage
- broker running in Docker container on host A, Spring Boot client with starter-artemis running (without Docker) on host B: 5-10% CPU usage
- broker running in Docker container on host A, Spring Boot client with starter-artemis (which uses JMS) in Docker container running on host A: ~40% CPU usage

I am still doing more research, just wanted to let you know the current state to no longer blame Artemis for showing bad figures.

Btw, an interesting side information: During idle both applications using only an artemis dependency (core & jms) only a ping message every 30 seconds is being exchanged. The application embedded in Spring Boot using the starter-artemis is veeeeeery talkative. Can't yet tell you what this is about, except that I saw something about *hornetq forced delivery seq*. I assume that because of the amount of messages the CPU usage goes from <5% to 5-10%.

**Update 2:**
Spring Boot with starter-artemis is talkative because by default it is using the `DefaultContainerFactory`, which polls. If there arent any messages within a given timeout it issues a *force pull* command, which is the reason for those *hornetq forced delivery seq* messages. In my core/jms tests I've used the asynchronous message handler, which is being provided by Spring Boot starter-artemis if you switch to the `SimpleContainerFactory`.

Comment: Have you gathered any thread dumps from the broker during this time to see what the problem might be? If so, what did they indicate? If not, why? Also, I would strongly encourage you to upgrade to the latest release.

Comment: Yeah, I've looked into the thread dump but didn't saw anything that would explain the behavior. Just some nio polling threads. Maybe thats because the application itself is not the problem. I've just updated the answer with some recent findings. Turns out that Docker seems to be at least somehow involved in the increased CPU usage.

Answer (score 2):

The broker has been recently improved (eg https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-2990) for scenario like these: I strongly suggest to try a more recent version.

If it won't going to fix your issue I suggest to run https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler/ to sample CPU usage (it would include GC, compilation and native stack traces too).

Consider that the original address/queue management was using synchronized operations that would make Java threads to heavily contend on hot path: this can cause kernel/system CPU cycles to be spent to manage it (remember: contended java locks are backed by OS mutex) and such CPU usage won't appear on JMX.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I'll upgrade as soon as possible.